# Converting Phone Number Format to 'XXX-XXX-XXXX'

Tags: sql, syntax, teradata

I have some code that I wrote in Teradata that joins 2 separate tables:

```
SELECT
A.*,
B.MTN_1

FROM
TABLE_1 AS A

JOIN
TABLE_2 AS B
ON A.ACCT_NUM=B.ACCT_NUM

WHERE A.MTN=B.MTN_1
```

The only problem is, MTN_1 is in `999-999-9999 (VARCHAR)` format.  MTN is in `9999999999 (Character Fixed)` format.  How can I change the Character Fixed format to match the 999-999-9999 format so I can use the columns in my join conditions?

Comment: Don't forget that for most of the world "XXX-XXX-XXXX" doesn't look anything like a phone number.  If you really do just care about North America, you might want to change your question to remove any mention of phone number and just talk about string formatting.  (Localized phone number formatting isn't simple, FYI.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the replace function:

```
SELECT A.*, B.MTN_1
FROM TABLE_1 AS A
JOIN TABLE_2 AS B ON A.ACCT_NUM=B.ACCT_NUM
WHERE A.MTN=REPLACE(B.MTN_1,"-","")
```

When using Teradata, which doesn't have a replace function, you can use substr and the concatenation operator:

```
SELECT A.*, B.MTN_1
FROM TABLE_1 AS A
JOIN TABLE_2 AS B ON A.ACCT_NUM=B.ACCT_NUM
WHERE A.MTN=SUBSTR(B.MTN_1,1,3) || SUBSTR(B.MTN_1,5,3) || SUBSTR(B.MTN_1,9,4)
```

Comment: I'm using Teradata...it seems to be looking for something to precede "REPLACE"

Comment: This allows you to match A.MTN with B.MTN_1 by giving them the same format. Your problem was that there are dashes in MTN_1 and no dashes in MTN, so the replace functions removes them, and indeed for the time of the comparaison, turns XXX-XXX-XXXX to XXXXXXXXXX.

Comment: Oh okay. Teradata. No replace function... I'll look further.

Comment: Thanks!  Will test it out when I get home.